# Знаки вопроса вместо русских букв при выборке из MS SQL Database

Tags: php, sql-server, кодировка, преобразование

возникла такая проблема, с которой уже борюсь второй день, а то и третий.
Подключаюсь через DSN к MS SQL Server 2019.
В Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio 18 во всех БД указана кодировка Cyrillic_General_CI_AS.

> Стоит отметить, что доступов на изменения у меня нет, только readonly.

Вот сам код на php с подключением и выборкой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот, собственно говоря, вывод в Postman Agent, тоже самое и в браузере.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался использовать CAST и CONVERT для колонки **DisplayName** в тип NVARCHAR(255), как и в БД.
Ничего не вышло, все тоже самое. Попробовал выводить в запросе напрямую кириллический текст

```
SELECT N'Приветствую' FROM Events; // вывод: Приветствую
```

То есть все отлично выводит. Отсюда начал задумываться, быть может неправильно установил кодировку в odbc_connect(), разные способы пробовал, все равно ничего не вышло.
Сразу хочу отметить, что далеко не разбирающийся в этом деле, выпала задача, с php тоже особо немного работал.

Вот что выдает Mangement Studio, напрямую если обращаться

```
SELECT DisplayName from Events;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если конвертировать в int, то выйдет очевидная ошибка, но с интересным содержанием

```
SELECT CAST(DisplayName AS INT) FROM Events;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если `SELECT N'Приветствую'` выводится нормально, а `SELECT DisplayName` вопросами, то, возможно, данные в базу легли неправильно.

Comment: В таком случае, задача в принципе нерешаема, поскольку доступов нет, а если что-то поменять по кодировкам у них, то все может полететь, поскольку к этой базе, как я понял, у них ещё данные подтягиваются откуда-то

Comment: Попробуйте в Management Studio напрямую подключиться к базе и выполнить запрос `SELECT DisplayName FROM Events`, чтобы удостовериться. Если прямой запрос тоже `???` возвращает, то явно проблема в том месте, где данные пишутся в таблицу. Можно также в бинарном виде `SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(max), DisplayName) FROM Events`, чтобы насчёт кодировок не сомневаться. Если данные лежат нормально, то коды символов будут разные, если `?`, то все символы будут кодироваться как `3F`.

Comment: Все нормально там отображается, русские буковки)

Comment: Хмм, т.е. данные нормально лежат и значит проблема всё-таки где-то на клиентской части. По PHP, к сожалению, не подскажу.

Comment: @i-one, хорошо, спасибо хоть и за это

Comment: Если русский работает в базе данных. Вы можете попробовать создать (X)HTML полностью на стороне SQL Server. Посмотрите мой ответ здесь: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5476ddac-fc71-48b9-8b4b-6bbc3a7cf5a2/html-code-inside-sql

Comment: вас там PDO и sqlsrv лишили,  или зачем с ODBC работать?